# How to understand the output of scipy's quadratic_assignment function?

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to use scipy's [quadratic_assignment](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.quadratic_assignment.html) function but I can't understand how the output can describe an optimal solution. Here is a minimal example where I compare a small matrix to itself:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import quadratic_assignment

# Parameters
n = 5
p = np.log(n)/n   # Approx. 32%

# Definitions
A = np.random.rand(n,n)<p

# Quadratic assignment
res = quadratic_assignment(A, A)

print(res.col_ind)
```

and the results seem to be random assignments:

```
[3 0 1 4 2]
[3 2 4 1 0]
[3 2 1 0 4]
[4 3 1 0 2]
[2 3 0 1 4]
...
```

However, according to the docs `col_ind` is supposed to be the *Column indices corresponding to the best permutation found of the nodes of B.* Since the input matrices are equal (B==A), I would thus expect the identity assignment `[0 1 2 3 4]` to pop out. Changing `n` to larger values does not help.

Is there something I am getting wrong?

Comment: Quadratic assignment is a NP-hard problem and the documentation states that the result is not guaranteed to be the optimal solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `quadratic_assignment` function (approximately) solves two types of problem: **quadratic assignment** and **graph matching**. These are mathematically very similar: the difference is that quadratic assignment involves *minimising* an objective function, whereas graph matching involves *maximising* that same function. [(Reference: scipy docs)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.quadratic_assignment.html#scipy.optimize.quadratic_assignment).

To distinguish between these two problems, the function accepts an option `maximize` (passed as a key:value pair in the `options` argument of the function). If not supplied, this defaults to `False` (i.e. the solution corresponds to the minimum of the function, i.e. the quadratic assignment problem rather than the graph matching problem).

```
quadratic_assignment(A, B)  # solves quadratic assignment
quadratic_assignment(A, B, options={'maximize': False})  # solves quadratic assignment
quadratic_assignment(A, B, options={'maximize': True})  # solves graph matching
```

Now, when you say *"Since the input matrices are equal (B==A), I would thus expect the identity assignment [0 1 2 3 4] to pop out"* – that's what would be expected for **graph matching**, i.e. the identity assignment is indeed the permutation of B that matches A better than any other (or strictly speaking: at least as well as any other).

So you would get your expected result by specifying `options={'maximize': True}` so that you get the solution to the graph matching problem rather than the default quadratic assignment:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import quadratic_assignment

# Parameters
n = 5
p = np.log(n)/n   # Approx. 32%

# Definitions
A = np.random.rand(n,n)<p

# Graph matching
res = quadratic_assignment(A, A, options={'maximize': True})

print(res.col_ind)
```

When I run this, I get the expected `[0 1 2 3 4]` around 97% of the time. It's not 100% because (a) the algorithm is approximate and "not guaranteed to be optimal" (per the docs) and (b) the way that you construct `A` could create degenerate cases where there are multiple equally good solutions.

Comment: very good answer